# svn: getting rid of the P flag from a checkout

Tags: svn

If I run `svnversion` on the working copy of one of my projects, I get a P suffix (partial working copy, from a sparse checkout, according to `svnversion --help`). I've tried to get rid of the P suffix but can't seem to do it, despite doing `svn update` or `svn cleanup`.

Besides blowing away the whole working copy, how can I? I'd like to have a clean checkout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
svn update --set-depth=infinity path/to/folder/with/P/suffix
```

The important part is the `--set-depth=infinity`

Comment: +1. Was already typing this answer. `--set-depth=infinity` worked for me.

Comment: Works for me too, but the problem keeps coming back though ! Still haven't found out why ! But at least I have a workaround ;) Thanks